# Extract decimal number from string and sum them up in excel

Tags: excel

I would like to extract decimal number from a string and sum them up.

For example:

```
A1= A1.55
B1=B2
```

In the C1 column, I would like to sum just the decimal number after the letter **A** and **B**. So my total in column **C** should be `= 1.55 + 2 = 3.55`

I found some example on the internet but this only works for rounded numbers, not decimal numbers

```
=SUMPRODUCT(RIGHT("00"&A1:B1,2)+0)
```

Comment: Do you want this only for `A` & `B` or it may increase?

Comment: the range could increase for example A1:K1

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1:B1,2,15))
```

As always, if your sample is not truly representative of your data, this simple formula will fail.

In this case, the relevant part of your data is that

- there will always be only a single non-numeric character preceding the value to sum.