# Sum only cells with prefix letter in a row

Tags: excel

I have data in Row 1 as follow:

A1 = 8 
A2 = 9
A3 = CN2.75
A4 = CN3

I would like the result in cell B2 = sum range A1 to A4 and only sum cells with prefix letter "CN".
 The sum result in cell B2 should be = 2.75 + 3 = 5.75

Comment: In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448717/extract-decimal-number-from-string-and-sum-them-up-in-excel/55449533#55449533) I have given you a RegEx function, which with a very minimal effort could be changed to suit your needs for this one. Just use a `If Left(CL.Value, 2) = "CN" Then` statement.

Comment: Create a helper `B` column with this function.
`=VALUE(IF("CN"=LEFT(A3; 2); MID(A3; 3;99); 0))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(+IF(LEFT(A1:A4,2)="CN",1,0),IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(A1:A4,LEN(A1:A4)-2)),0))
```

Prefer even JvDV's Version from the comments, even more efficient

Enter as an array formula `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: `{=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(A1:A4,2)="CN")*(IFERROR(RIGHT(A1:A4,LEN(A1:A4)-2),0)))}` could be a good alternative

Comment: would even be the better alternative - I was sure to need the `value` after a `right`. I've edited me answer to point to your version